# What does ^ symbol mean in an R regex?

Tags: r, regex

Does anyone what the ^ symbol means in R?

Here is the context:

```
mito.genes <- grep("^MT-", rownames(pbmc@data), value = T)
```

This command is used to extract only the mitochondrial genes from a large list of genes.  This came from the Seurat tutorial which can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/satijalab/satijalab.github.io/master/seurat/pbmc-tutorial.Rmd

These mitochondrial genes all share the prefix "MT-" Example genes are MT-ND1, MT-ND2

I am trying to improve my understanding so i can adapt this command to extract other sets of genes by the characters in their names.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check out `?base::regex`

Comment: I have never used r in my life, but it could be some regex-pattern? There ^ means start of line

Comment: It's not an R symbol really, but a regular expression symbol.

Comment: read this https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: I don't know R, but `grep` is a program used for searching through text. You can look at those docs: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

Comment: Outside of regular expressions, the `^` symbol denotes exponentiation, e.g., `2^3 = 8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `regex` meaning it start with MT. so basically whenever you have `"^MT-"` it means looking for anything which start with `MT-`